# ResourceBundle.getString removed backslash character

Tags: java, resourcebundle, backslash

I tried to get a resource from a file path from a properties file.

Property File:

```
info_path=c:\Info\output
```

Java:

```
String path = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundle_name").getString("info_path");
```

Result:
C:Infooutput

I would need to set the file:

```
info_path=c:\\Info\\output
```

Is this the default behavior? or would it depend on the file encoding?
The file is using SJIS encoding by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better of using forward slash in your property files, instead of some workaround. By the way no matter you are on Unix/Linux or Windows, forward slash works well, in this context at least. After all Java is platform independent. ;)

> P.S. Its better to use relative path.

Comment: Thanks. I actually got to the same conclusion too. forward slash is platform independent. :)